# Are new diseases without "Syndrome" in its name being added to English?

Tags: etymology

I can think of new syndromes being added to English in recent times. For example, AIDS (acquired immunodeficiency syndrome) is a syndrome, as is SARS (Severe acute respiratory syndrome).

By contrast, when thinking of diseases without "Syndrome" in its name, I can think of malaria, or heart disease, and Ebola, but nothing recent.

Are new diseases without "Syndrome" in its name being added to English?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as framed it is not about the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, *syndrome* does **not** really name a disease (though it is sometimes used that way - see below).  *Syndrome* refers to a set of *symptoms*. Typically, symptoms are described before the disease causing those symptoms is known. When causes are understood, one or more disease names are then sometimes associated with the causes.

It is true, however, that sometimes a name for a set of symptoms is carried over as the name of a disease. AIDS is perhaps a case of this. The name was first used for a set of symptoms. Later, the HIV virus was understood as a cause. But, perhaps especially because it is possible for HIV to be present without the AIDS symptoms, the name typically used for the disease is also AIDS.

Comment: Syndrome, as well as *disease* and *disorder*, is used to name new diseases all the time. It all depends on who's doing the naming and how the researchers/medical community accepts it.

Comment: @medica: See my second paragraph. Sometimes a disease is named after a syndrome, which describes symptoms. The syndrome itself always describes symptoms. Real understanding of a disease involves more than description of symptoms. The reason more "diseases" seem to be named "XYZ syndrome" recently is precisely because of this distinction: First the symptoms are named (as a syndrome). Later, either the same name is kept for the disease, at least informally, or another name is used to refer to the disease.

Comment: In the past, the name of the syndrome (set of symptoms) itself did not tend to include the word "syndrome". Now it does, precisely to make note of the fact that it only denotes symptoms (so far). It is a way for medical professionals to underline the fact that they are (so far) only describing symptoms.

Comment: I do agree with one thing you said: *It all depends on who's doing the naming and how the researchers/medical community accepts it.* That does not make *syndrome* a good name for a disease. You *can* name a disease anything. If you name it using *syndrome* then you are explicitly referring to symptoms. That was my point.

Comment: @medica:  #2 answers the OP question, I think: Yes, *syndrome* is used more now.  No, it does not really describe the disease itself (beyond symptoms). Yes, sometimes no other name is used for the disease. Yes, sometimes another name *is* used for the disease, once more is known about it besides just describing symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are. What about Hendra Virus, variant Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease, and Marburg virus?

Comment: Is there a standard way to refer to the disease? Eg Clostridium tetani causes tetanus; prions cause CJD; Marburg virus causes ...?

Comment: Technically Marburg virus causes Marburg virus disease, but that seems a bit silly to me.

Comment: So the metonym 'He's got Marburg / Marburg virus' would be used?

Comment: I guess? It's such an usual disease I've never heard anyone talk about it. Hendra virus would only be called that I think... it's named after a suburb, so you wouldn't say "he caught Hendra"

Comment: I've found MVD for the disease in Wikipedia, but they only use 'an outbreak of Hendra virus' or the equivalent: you're right, it _must_ be rare.

Comment: Only seven people have caught Hendra virus so far (with four deaths.) It's big news when an outbreak occurs. Several hundred have had Marburg virus.

Comment: Ebola seems to have greater notoriety: Ebola virus disease (EVD), Ebola hemorrhagic fever (EHF), or simply Ebola [Wikipedia]